# React force componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class FirstName extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            submitted: false
        };
    }
    getName () {
        var name = this.refs.firstName.value;
        this.setState(function() {
          this.props.action(name);
        });
    }
    handleSubmit (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true }, function() {
            this.props.actionID(2);
            this.props.activeNav('color');
        });
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>tell us your first name</h2>
                <form>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        ref="firstName"
                        onChange={this.getName.bind(this)}
                    />
                    <div className="buttons-wrapper">
                        <button href="#">back</button>
                        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>continue</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>  
        );
    }
};

class PickColor extends React.Component {
    backToPrevious (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.actionID(1);
        this.props.activeNav('name');
    }
    goToNext (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.actionID(3);
        this.props.activeNav('design');
        this.props.displayIconsHolder(true);
    }
    getColorValue(event) {
        this.props.color(event.target.getAttribute("data-color"));
    }
    render () {
        var colors = ['red', 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'],
            colorsLink = [];

        colors.forEach(el => { 
            colorsLink.push(<li 
                                data-color={el} 
                                key={el} 
                                onClick={this.getColorValue.bind(this)} 
                                ref={el}>
                                    {el}
                            </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <section>
                <ul>
                    {colorsLink}
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.backToPrevious.bind(this)}>back</button>
                <button onClick={this.goToNext.bind(this)}>continue</button>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

class ConfirmSingleIcon extends React.Component {
    goBack () {
        this.props.goBack();
    }
    confirmCaptionandIcon (event) {
        var optionID = event.target.getAttribute("data-option-id"),
            name = event.target.getAttribute("data-option-name");
        this.props.setOptionID(optionID);
        this.props.setIcon(1, name, optionID, false);
    }
    goNext () {
        this.props.goNext();
    }
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.currentState);
        var options = [],
            that = this;
        this.props.iconOptionsList.forEach(function(el){
            options.push(<li onClick={that.confirmCaptionandIcon.bind(that)} key={el.option} data-option-name={el.option} data-option-id={el.id}>{el.option}</li>);
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Choose your caption</h2>
                <h3>
                    {this.props.selectedIcon}
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    {options}
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.goBack.bind(this)} >back</button>
                <button onClick={this.goNext.bind(this)} >confirm</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ConfirmCaption extends React.Component {
    handleClick () {
        var currentState = this.props.currentState;
        this.props.setIcon(currentState.icon_ID, currentState.selectedIcon, currentState.option_ID, true);
        this.props.setIconVisiblity(true);
        this.props.setIconListVisiblity(false);
    }
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.currentState);
        return (
            <div>
                <p onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>confirm icon and caption</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ChooseIcon extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            icons: [],
            iconList: true,
            confirmIcon: false,
            confirmCaption: false,
            selectedIconOptions: '',
            icon_ID: '',
            option_ID: '',
            selectedIcon: ''
        };
        this.setOptionID = this.setOptionID.bind(this);

        this.setIconVisiblity = this.setIconVisiblity.bind(this);
        this.setIconListVisiblity = this.setIconListVisiblity.bind(this);
    }
    setOptionID (id) {
        this.setState({ option_ID: id })
    }
    setIconVisiblity (onOff) {
        this.setState({ confirmIcon: onOff })
    }
    setIconListVisiblity (onOff) {
        this.setState({ iconList: onOff })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var url = `http://local.tshirt.net/get-options`;
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ icons:res.data.icons });
        });
    }
    handleClick (event) {
        var iconId = event.target.getAttribute("data-icon-id"),
            that = this;
        this.state.icons.forEach(function(el){
            if(el.id == iconId){
                that.setState(
                    { 
                        confirmIcon: true,
                        iconList: false,
                        selectedIcon: el.name,
                        icon_ID: iconId,
                        selectedIconOptions: el.option
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
    goBack () {
        this.setState(
            { 
                confirmIcon: false,
                iconList: true
            }
        );
    }
    goNext () {
        this.setState(
            { 
                confirmIcon: false,
                iconList: false,
                confirmCaption: true
            }
        );
    }
    render () {
        var icons = [];
        this.state.icons.forEach(el => {
            icons.push(<li data-icon-id={el.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={el.name}>{el.name}</li>);
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.iconList ? <IconList icons={icons} /> : ''}
                {this.state.confirmIcon ? <ConfirmSingleIcon goBack={this.goBack.bind(this)} 
                                                             goNext={this.goNext.bind(this)} 
                                                             setIcon={this.props.setIcon} 
                                                             selectedIcon={this.state.selectedIcon}
                                                             iconOptionsList ={this.state.selectedIconOptions}
                                                             setOptionID={this.setOptionID}
                                                             currentState={this.state} /> : ''}

                {this.state.confirmCaption ? <ConfirmCaption currentState={this.state} 
                                                             setIcon={this.props.setIcon}
                                                             setIconVisiblity={this.setIconVisiblity}
                                                             setIconListVisiblity={this.setIconListVisiblity}  /> : ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class IconList extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Pick your icon</h2>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.icons}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Forms extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var form;
        switch(this.props.formID) {
            case 1:
                form = <FirstName action={this.props.action} actionID={this.props.switchComponent} activeNav={this.props.activeNav} />
                break;
            case 2:
                form = <PickColor displayIconsHolder={this.props.seticonsHolder} color={this.props.colorVal} actionID={this.props.switchComponent} activeNav={this.props.activeNav} />
                break;
            case 3:
                form = <ChooseIcon setIcon={this.props.setOptionA} />
                break;
        }
        return (
            <section>
                {form}
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Forms;
```

"ChooseIcon" is a component that will get used 3 times therefore everytime I get to it I need to bring its state back as if it was the first time.

Ideally I would need to make this ajax call everytime:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var url = `http://local.tshirt.net/get-options`;
    axios.get(url)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ icons:res.data.icons });
    });
}
```

is there a way to manually call componentDidMount perhaps from a parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `ChooseIcon` component 3 times inside the same parent component, I would suggest you to do the ajax in `componentDidMount` of the parent component like this (exaclty how you have in your example, in terms of code)

```
componentDidMount() {
  var url = `http://local.tshirt.net/get-options`;
  axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({ icons:res.data.icons });
  });
}
```

and then pass this data down to the `ChooseIcon` component

```
render() {
  return (
  //do your stuff
    <ChooseIcon icons={this.state.icons}/>
  )
}
```

after this you will only need to set the received props in your `ChooseIcon`component, for that you only need to change one line in it's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        icons: props.icons,  // Changed here!
        iconList: true,
        confirmIcon: false,
        confirmCaption: false,
        selectedIconOptions: '',
        icon_ID: '',
        option_ID: '',
        selectedIcon: ''
    };
    this.setOptionID = this.setOptionID.bind(this);

    this.setIconVisiblity = this.setIconVisiblity.bind(this);
    this.setIconListVisiblity = this.setIconListVisiblity.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 20):

React handles component lifecycle through `key` attribute. For example:

```
<ChooseIcon key={this.props.formID} setIcon={this.props.setOptionA} />
```

So every time your `key` (it can be anything you like, but unique) is changed component will unmount and mount again, with this you can easily control `componentDidMount` callback.

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but how do you change components' key?

Answer (score 2):

The parent component can use a ref to call the function directly.

However, trying to force this function feels like a smell. Perhaps lifting the state higher up the component tree would solve this problem. This way, the parent component will tell ChooseIcon what to show, and there will not be a need to call componentDidMount again. Also, I assume the Ajax call can also occur once.